# How to create a ModelCopy in correct way (django)

Tags: python, django, model

I have a resume model

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sex = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default=1)
    education = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)

    expierence = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=EXPERIENCE_CHOICES)
    expect_post = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=POST_CHOICES)
    expect_salary = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=SALARY_CHOICES)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True)
    .....
```

Now I want to send a copy of one resume to a recruiter(requirement is: a recruiter can not see update, so I have to do this).

So I do:

```
class ResumeCopy(Resume):
    def copy(self, resume):
        for f in self._meta.fields:
            setattr(self, f.name, getattr(resume, f.name))
```

But it would implicitly create a Not NUll `OneToOneField` named `resume_ptr` in this way.
I don't need this field, is there any better way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstract model that's base for both `Resume` and `ResumeCopy`.

```
class BaseResume(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sex = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default=1)
    education = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)

    expierence = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=EXPERIENCE_CHOICES)
    expect_post = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=POST_CHOICES)
    expect_salary = models.IntegerField(blank=False, choices=SALARY_CHOICES)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True)

class Resume(BaseResume):
    pass

class ResumeCopy(BaseResume):
    pass
```